# Modern smartphone with a physical keyboard

Tags: keyboards, smartphones

So far, it appears the only thing I can get if I want a device that's even *remotely* modern is the [Blackberry Priv](http://us.blackberry.com/smartphones/priv-by-blackberry/overview.html), but I could be wrong, hence the question.

My hard requirements (it's a dealbreaker without them):

- The keyboard, as mentioned in the topic.
- Decent app ecosystem (this eliminates all other BB devices)
- OS that still gets security updates
- Good performance (the UI should not hitch and stutter under daily use)
- Supported on the Verizon network

Secondary concerns (nice to haves):

- Can be rooted/jailbroken
- At least a 1080p screen
- Battery life should last a full day under light use
- OS still gets feature updates

Price no object; nearly any phone can be had via carrier discounts or secondhand.

Comment: I don't think you'll find such a thing meeting those requirements.  A quick google search gives me this: http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/best-qwerty-phones/ and there isn't much to choose from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Blackberry Priv runs Android and has a physical keyboard, 4K display, Snapdragon 808 and 3GB of ram (so it should not be slow).

Its the closest thing from what you are looking for I guess.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.. it's a shame that there's only one decent keyboard phone out there right now, and it's created by a company with questionable longevity. Still, thank you for your research.

Answer (score 0):

For a 2018 answer, the [**BlackBerry KEY2**](https://blackberrymobile.com/product/blackberry-key2/).

#### [Specs](https://blackberrymobile.com/specifications/keytwo/)

- A great **physical keyboard**, which doubles as a trackpad for scrolling, navigation, and text selection, and allows for custom programmable macros to instantly launch anything
- Android **Oreo 8.1**
- **SnapDragon 660, Kryo 260 8-Core @ 2.2 GHz x 4 + 1.8GHz x 4** and **6GB RAM**

As for your nice-to-haves:

- **Can be rooted** (e.g. [CyanogenMod](https://cyanogenmod-roms.apk.cafe/blackberry/key2))
- **1080p** screen (433 PPI)
- **3500 mAh** of battery (~25 hrs of mixed use)
- OS will likely get **feature updates** (KEYone Oreo updates are rolling out at the time of writing)

Unfortuantely it fails your "Supported on the Verizon network" requirement, since it's GSM/GPRS/EDGE, but Verizon only supports CDMA. I hope it's not still a deal-breaker to transfer to a GSM provider like T-Mobile or AT&T.